# Embed Video in DreamweaverCC and Phonegap not working correctly

Tags: android, html5-video, dreamweaver, phonegap-build

## Hi all.

I am making a dreamweaverCC mobile App. I have everything working perfectly through the phonegap build and I can get my .apk.

However the html 5 "video" tag dose not seem to be working correctly.

For instance , the following works correctly when linked to a movie on the internet, and I can play the video correctly and without a problem on my phone.

```
<video poster="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Teddy_bear_27.jpg/250px-Teddy_bear_27.jpg" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

However the local video file will display the place holder and even show the "controls" but it keeps showing a spining box as if "loading" but it never actually dose:

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls>
    <source src="videos/broken_compas.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

So the question is : why is Android not picking up the embedded video ?

**Remember , this is been packed through the DreamweaverCC and phone-gap for use on a mobile (.apk) file.**

Both videos work fine on the dreamweaver "live" option.

I know the video is been packed due to the file size of the APK.

Is is a simple file refference path issue ?

Comment: Following this up , I hardcoded the location into the HTML <video> tag . I know this will only work with the phone I am testing with, and I KNOW it's not suitable , or a solution:


`<video width="350" height="600" loop preload="auto" >
 <source  type="video/m4v" src="file:///storage/sdcard0/Movies/broken_compas.mp4" ></video>`


If there is a direct path , like a universal path that Androids installs embeded movies to upon installion of .APK file, please let me know, Cheers